# Spring validation don't follow the POJO principle

Tags: java, spring, validation

I've read this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

I see that the spring's approach of validating a form is to annotate the
properties of a object (which can be a POJO), with validation constraints
like @Min, @Max, @Size, etc..

This is not the best approach to mess-up POJO objects with this 
annotations.

How do you write your code for validation a form in spring framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring offers a design for validation (and data binding) that does not exclude either one of them. Spring features a Validator interface that you can use to validate objects.

The *Validator* interface works using an *Errors* object so that while validating, validators can report validation failures to the Errors object.

Person POJO:

```
public class Person {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  // the usual getters and setters...
}
```

Implementing a *Validator*:

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    /**
    * This Validator validates just Person instances
    */
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge()  110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
    }
}
```

Documentaction about [Validation, Data Binding in Spring Framework 3.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some debate about whether or not you should use annotations on the POJO or not. 
My personal opinion is that if you are not going to be sharing the POJO between modules, annotation configuration is perfectly acceptable.

If you want the validation constrains to be configured without annotations, you should look at [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-xml-configuration.html)'s (Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation of this JSR 349) XML configuration. The reference for that configuration is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-xml-configuration.html).

Also check out [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-hibernate-validator) (somewhat older) post for a tutorial.